# What is "user-replaceable"?

Tags: vocabulary

Read this sentence:

> iPhone's battery is not *user-replaceable*.

I am a user & I can replace my iPhone's battery. Just use some special tool, take the iPhone's case out & replace. Why they say "not user-replaceable"? Does "user" mean "average user"?

Comment: I think the fact that you need a special tool shows that the battery is not user-replaceable. (Or, at least, it's not _designed_ to be user-replaceable).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't really have to do with English, they simply mean that they don't want and don't recommend that users attempt to replace the battery.  There may be legal consequences to this notice.  For example, a battery that has actually been replaced by a user may be a legal grounds (reason) for Apple to void (cancel) the warranty.

Comment: Also there may be some safety issue if the user replaces it, which could otherwise result in manufacturer liability. Maybe no problem for you, but for others (average user)? Manufacturers cannot take that chance, otherwise they could face liability if the customer made some mistake and caused a safety hazard.

Answer (score 0):

> Why they say "not user-replaceable"?

They're lying.  Something that I understand happens in a lot of languages.

They want you to believe that the battery is not user-replaceable so that you will pay them either for the service on the device or for a whole new device.  So they tell customers that it can't be done.

Comment: they should say iPhone battery is not easily replaceable by non-technician person.

Comment: @Tim, how would that mislead you into buying a thing or a service you wouldn't otherwise?